# VSCode key binding for next editor in stack

Tags: visual-studio-code, sublimetext3, key-bindings

In Sublime I have a keybinding set up like so:

```
{ "keys": ["super+j"], "command": "next_view_in_stack" },
```

I am trying to recreate this behavior in VSCode with

```
{
    "key":"cmd+j",
    "command":"workbench.action.previousEditor"
},
```

but instead of going to my previous tab, it goes one tab to the left. Is there any concept of a "stack" of editors like in Sublime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to configure two different key bindings to get this working correctly.

First configure `workbench.action.quickOpenPreviousRecentlyUsedEditorInGroup` to Cmd + J, **and set its *when expression* to** `!inQuickOpen`.

Also, to allow using the shortcut repeatedly once the quick open list is already open, you need to also configure `workbench.action.quickOpenNavigateNext` to Cmd + J, and set its when expression to `inQuickOpen`.

For me this worked when I wanted to configure Alt + Tab for the recent file cycling shortcut. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

There are the following commands that may give you the functionality you're looking for:

```
{ "key": "ctrl+tab",       "command": "workbench.action.openNextRecentlyUsedEditorInGroup" },
{ "key": "ctrl+shift+tab", "command": "workbench.action.openPreviousRecentlyUsedEditorInGroup" },
```

Comment: This is close, but it only allows you to pop off the stack once. Going further back is not possible without hitting the arrow keys

Answer (score 0):

use

```
'alt + leftArrow' & 'alt + rightArrow"    // switch between recent stack tabs
```